# Using iTextSharp to stamp form field with bold text

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a field in a form that I want to fill with both bold and regular text, rather than creating two separate fields.  I know I can do this:

```
var normalfont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA);
            var boldfont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD);
            var phrase = new Phrase();
            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Name: ", boldfont));
            phrase.Add(new Chunk(line.LastName + ", " + line.FirstName, normalfont));
 form.SetField("name", phrase);
```

But then how do I set the field in the form to the phrase I just created?

Is there a better way to do this or should I just break up my fields?

Comment: It is the best solution...

Comment: @BhupendraShukla - OK then, but then how do I set the form field to the phrase?

Comment: Do you want to fill the pdf with the phrase you just created. Like filling form field with the phrase.

Comment: @BhupendraShukla - yes, as in SetField...